# Xamarin Can't View Provisioning Profiles in Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin. I Have created a app and trying to integrate Push Notification in IOS. But When I try to add Apple Developer Account to Xamarin studio it gets added but when i click on 'View Details' it does not show me the Signing Identities and Provisioning Profiles.
But I Can view it in X-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I advise you to install Visual Studio for Mac, it's the successor of Xamarin Studio, Xamarin Studio will no longer be maintained.

It's normal, Xamarin Studio does not support all the feature of Xcode, the compilation is based on Xcode so for certains actions you need to use Xcode, it's more clear and easy.